# Number of processes with same name in Linux [c]

Tags: c, linux, process, grep

I have problem with achieving int output of numbers of running processes with same PID.
Eg.

```
ps aux | grep program1
```

shows me 3 process, 2 of my main app (parent and child). I wanna know how to get it in C. my point is to get like number "2" because i have two processes with same name. As far as i know i cannot get terminal output to C variable so I really dont have idea how to get it.The problem is that I must get this information on progmam2 not program1.

Thanks!

Comment: what's the output of the above command?

Comment: root     15783  0.0  0.0   4088   428 pts/2    S    10:52   0:00 ./program1   something like that but x2 because of child process

Comment: You should read about the `proc` filesystem. You can read the name of a process in `/proc/PROCESS_ID/comm`.

Comment: What do you mean by *how to get it in C*? Do you mean you want to read this information using a C program? You need to be a bit more clear on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Look at the source for `ps` and see hit the command does it?

Comment: @iharob, I have some snippet to search pids by name of process but it preety advanced and i had hope for something easier.

Comment: @lurker - yea, i mean how i can get number of process with name "program1" in application program2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out, I think this is not advanced at all

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void readProcessName(const char *const comm, char name[PATH_MAX])
{
    int fd;
    int size;

    fd = open(comm, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
        return;
    if ((size = read(fd, name, PATH_MAX)) > 1)
        name[size - 1] = '\0';
    else
        name[0] = '\0';
    close(fd);
}

void findProcessByName(const char *const find)
{
    DIR           *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    dir = opendir("/proc");
    if (dir == NULL)
        return;
    chdir("/proc");
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        struct stat st;
        char        comm[PATH_MAX];
        const char *name;
        char        procname[PATH_MAX];

        name = entry->d_name;
        if (stat(name, &st) == -1)
            continue;
        if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode) == 0)
            continue;
        /* this will skip .. too, and any hidden file? there are no hidden files I think */
        if (name[0] == '.')
            continue;
        snprintf(comm, sizeof(comm), "%s/comm", name);
        if (stat(comm, &st) == -1)
            continue;
        readProcessName(comm, procname);
        if (strcmp(procname, find) == 0)
            printf("%s pid: %s\n", procname, name);
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    findProcessByName("process-name-here");
    return 0;
}
```